# "Parsing error: No babel config file detected" when IDE not open at Vue projects root directory

Tags: javascript, vue.js, babeljs, eslint

I stumbled into a problem where in VS Code, when a Vue project is created and not open at root directory of the Vue project, babel.config.js wouldn't load and IDE would be confused as to where the babel config is.
[image: error when running vue project not at root]

All of my files show an error on the first character of any javascript/vue file reading
`No Babel config file detected for [#]... or configure babel so  that it can find the config files.`

Comment: ESLint may not be able to find your project's working directories automatically if you don't have a `.eslintrc.json` file into the project root directory.

Answer (score 126, accepted):

Adding the block to `settings.json` will solve this issue:

```
"eslint.workingDirectories": [
        {"mode": "auto"}
 ],
```

To access `settings.json` file, click `Ctrl+,` or from, File > Preferences > Settings,
then type eslint in the search bar, find *Edit in settings.json* in Options.

Comment: Getting "Unknown Configuration Setting" for eslint

Comment: Thank you! This is the only thing that worked to address the dreaded  `Failed to load plugin '@babel-parser' declared in '--config': Cannot find module '@babel-parser/eslint-plugin'` and related errors. I hope adding this message can help others find this solution.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I wouldn't have found it alone... The question is: why isn't it set automatically and where is this explanation in the documentation?

Comment: 8/5/23 -> the `settings.json` file is in the `.vscode` folder located at project root

Answer (score 24):

Two ways fix this issue, It's worked me 100%.

I'm using react.js. But I successfully fixed this issue. I think this solution will be helpful for you.

I've variously attempted to either set `requireConfigFile` to false or to create some sort of Babel config, in an `.eslintrc.js`, in a `.babelrc` (or Babel Configuratio file), and in a "babel" in `package.json`, all to no effect.

Method 1 - add this codes into .eslintrc.js

***.eslintrc.js***

```
"parser": '@babel/eslint-parser',
"parserOptions": {
    "requireConfigFile": false,
}
```

Method 2 - install this package `@babel/core`

```
npm i --save-dev @babel/core
```

***.babelrc***

```
{
    "presets": ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"],
    "plugins": ["@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining"]
}
```

Comment: 2nd solution doesn't work. did not try first, as that is not a solution.

Comment: 2nd solution is React-specific, but this question should be answered in a stack-agnostic way, or specific to Vue, which is one of the original tags.

Comment: Method 1 worked for me, but the filename was .eslintrc (no ".js").

Comment: Method 1 worked for me, but I had to define `parser` inside `parserOptions`

Answer (score 7):

https://babeljs.io/docs/en/config-files
Babel expects your config file to be at root level, so in order to un-confuse your IDE you need to create an eslint setting for VSCodes extention. Under vscode-eslint settings switch to workspace on the top tab, then scroll to:

Eslint: Options

The eslint options object to provide args normally passed to eslint when executed from a command line (see https://eslint.org/docs/developer-guide/nodejs-api#eslint-class).

**Edit in settings.json** <-click on that

Vs code will make a `.vscode/` folder inside which a `settings.json`file was created. There add this line:

```json
{
    "eslint.options": {
        "configFile": "\\ABSOLUTE\\PATH\\TO\\YOUR\\PROJECT\\VUE_PROJECT\\babel.config.js"
    }
}
```

This will tell the IDE what to do.

Comment: It doesn't solve the problem, instead it sets babel config as eslint config, hence all the eslint errors and warning will disable due to wrong file path for eslint. Looks like it solves the problem but it actually disables eslint :-D

Answer (score 3):

Create a file inside your application with name **.eslintrc.js**
and paste this code:

```
module.exports = {
  extends: 'eslint-config-antife',
  plugins: [
    "babel",
    "html",
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In my little Vue app,

Add : "requireConfigFile":false in my package.json made it Alright!

```
 },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "root": true,
    "env": {
      "node": true
    },
    "extends": [
      "plugin:vue/essential",
      "eslint:recommended"
    ],
    "parserOptions": {
      "parser": "@babel/eslint-parser",
      "requireConfigFile":false
    },
    "rules": {}
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this when I amended some of the script settings in package.json. Not precisely sure what mistake I made: I just undid all typing in this file, and things started working again.

Answer (score 0):

Again install ES lint from Visual Studio. This problem will be solve. First uninstall ES Lint and then again install ES Lint.

Comment: Of course is should be "ES Lint" mentioned here. There can be no need to uninstall it as it like the IDE is pointing directly to search in open directory but it can be manually pointed to take specific path or use it automatically.

Comment: sorry about misspelling. But it is works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are on the right directory of the project when you run your linter commands. That was my case.

Answer (score 0):

This simple fix worked for me...

##### Get relative path to babel.config.json

Right-click on the babel.config.json file and in the context menu '**Copy Relative Path**' then added this path to my `configFile` property in the .eslintrc.js

##### .eslintrc.js

```
...
  parser: "@babel/eslint-parser",
  parserOptions: {
    sourceType: 'module',
    babelOptions: {
      configFile: 'aaa/bbb/ccc/babel.config.json' // <- workspace relative path
    }
  },
...
```

##### Disable & Re-enable Plugin

Then just **disable the vscode-eslint** plugin for your workspace then **re-enable it**. No more red squiggly lines.